# index out of band when trying to select a message using protractor

Tags: javascript, testing, xpath, protractor

I am trying to select a warning message "unassigned amount.." with this HTML code 
[image: HTML code for warning message]

I tried to select it using this line of code

```
  var warning=element.all(by.xpath('.//span[.="Unassigned Amount = 20.00"]')).filter(function (elm) {
    return elm.isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayed) {
        return isDisplayed;
    });
});
```

but I got this error from protractor :
[image: Error Transcript written below]

```
Message:
    Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(xpath, .//span[.="Unassigned Amount = 20.00"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your strict equality check inside the XPath expression is the problem because of the extra spaces around the text. Try with [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains):

```
.//span[contains(., "Unassigned Amount = 20.00")]
```

You can also solve it with [`by.cssContainingText` locator](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText):

```
element.all(by.cssContainingText("span[data-for=APIInvoiceAmount]", "Unassigned Amount = 20.00"))
```